# Unable to open invalid jpg file

Tags: jpeg

A few days ago I took pictures from my camera and uploaded them to my computer.

Now the photos that I took few days ago was appear to be corrupted or invalid format.

I have tried use third party software and repair tools but have been unable to solve this problem.

I get the error `invalid file` but extension is `jpg`.

Comment: Can you upload them again?

Comment: upload the image? actually the images was stored into sd card

Comment: If you have a program which can show the hex values of a file, check the images. If they are really jpegs, then there should be 'JFIF' from the 6th position on (or possibly 'Exif' if the image contains meta-data.

Comment: erm i use one of the programs it seems all the hex codes are YYYYYYYY

Comment: any other solutions to this? i need to open the pictures!

Comment: If they're corrupted beyond repair then there's nothing you can do.